# how can i use set_userdata in codeigniter4 for adding session data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am migrating codeigniter 2 to codeigniter 4.
I am facing lot of discrepencies.
Ex set_userdata. Its not available in codeigniter 4.

how can i use set_userdata in  codeigniter4 exactly like codeigniter 2.
Please help

Comment: maybe it's worth to mention, CI 4.x is a complete re-write and *it is more appropriate to think of converting your app, rather than upgrading it*, see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_4xx.html

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting you as per [CI doc](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).
Initialize session by

```
$session = \Config\Services::session($config); // $config is optional here
```

then,

```
$newdata = [
        'username'  => 'johndoe',
        'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
        'logged_in' => TRUE
];

$session->set($newdata);
```

Or

```
$session->set('some_name', 'some_value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain to you the easy way. In CI4 you will need to initialized the session library

In Controller

```php
$session = \Config\Services::session();
$sessionData = [
    'username' => 'John Doe',
    'phone' => 123545678,
    'role' => 'Teacher',
    'status' => 'Active'
];
$session->set($sessionData);
```

To Read the Data it is as simple as

```php
echo $session->get('username');
```

For More information just visit the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session#)

Answer (score 0):

[From the doc](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data),

> You can simply assign data to the $_SESSION array, as with any other variable. Or as a property of $this->session.

> Alternatively, the old method of assigning it as “userdata” is also available. That however passing an array containing your new data to the set_userdata() method.

it looks like you can use the `set` command with an array.

```
$newdata = [
        'username'  => 'johndoe',
        'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
        'logged_in' => TRUE
];

$session->set($newdata);
```

or use it like that to set a single value

```
$session->set('some_name', 'some_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello if I can understand your question. You want to set a session data.
Here is what you will do to solve this particular issue.
Load the session library by using any these `session()` or `service('session')`

```php
$session = session();
$session->set('data_index', $data);
```

Reference the document [CI4 Doc](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=count#countAllResults)

Answer (score 0):

You can set session value in Codeigniter4 as:

```
session()->set('session_name','session_value');
```

Comment: Welrico Dcosta, you should check before edit. Again you add the syntax error.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me where is the syntax error??